# How to log in in one script, and than continue working in other?

Tags: php, session

I created a small PHP CMS for a website, and I am not fixing up logging in with credentials.

I created a separate login.php page that processes login (error checking, etc.,), and other pages for the CMS itself.

I have turned on

```
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
```

and created

```
$_SESSION['SESSION_EXPIRY'] = time() + SESSION_TIMEOUT;
```

I also have start and destroy session stuff implemented.

All works on the login.php script nicely. But when I try checking in  $_SESSION['SESSION_EXPIRY' in other files, I got 0 as a result - the session is not passed further.

I don't understand how can I pass session stuff from script to script, and would appreciate if someone would give me some guidelines.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you use `session_start()` in every file?

Comment: Aw hell. I was bashing my head with this for hours. Thank you. Can you pls. answer below, so I can select as answer.